# Qt OpenGL framebuffer creates at one PC, but fails at another

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

So, there is two PCs with Windows 8.1 x64. First has installed Qt 5.7 SDK, second doesn't.
At first PC the following C++ Qt5 code works successfully:

```
int big_width = 1392;
int big_height = 1040;
int small_width = 696;
int small_height = 520;
format.setSamples(4);
format.setAttachment(QGLFramebufferObject::Depth);

framebuffer_big = new QGLFramebufferObject(big_width, big_height, format);
framebuffer_small = new QGLFramebufferObject(small_width, small_height, format);
```

And at the second PC I'm watching in Windows console the following:

```
[qglframebufferobject.cpp line 549] GL Error: 1280
QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
[qglframebufferobject.cpp line 549] GL Error: 1280
QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
QGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
```

So, I upgraded video driver at second PC, and it hadn't effect. And, of course, some required dll's are provided.

---

The question is this: how to fix listed above errors at second PC?

Comment: Try to display the openglVersion you are using in both cases. In the second one what append if you also add a colorAttachment

Comment: @DraykoonD I tried `qDebug()<<QString::fromStdString(   std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(   glGetString(GL_VERSION)   ))   ); ` on both PCs. At first I got `"4.5.0 NVIDIA 365.19"`. At second PC there was doom of the program: `termiante after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid   This application has requested the Runtime it in unusual way. Please contact the application`s support team for more information.` I have no idea what a problem could cause it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promblem was following: I have been using Microsoft Windows RDP. Through it impossible to start normally Qt OpenGL application. It seems like Microsoft or Digia screwed up!